# Getting TCP Socket statistics in Windows

Tags: windows, sockets, networking

Is there a way to get a specific socket statistics in windows? I'm most interested in the number of retransmissions a specific socket had, and doing it without using winpcap or similar solutions.

Windows should store such an interesting number somewhere, no?

Answer (score 1):

The global information is also available through Performance Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see of any way to get this information per TCP connection (or socket). However you can get [global statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalstatistics.aspx).